# How to copy a file in Python with a progress bar?

Tags: python, file-io

When copying large files using `shutil.copy()`, you get no indication of how the operation is progressing..

I have put together something that works - it uses a simple ProgressBar class (which simple returns a simple ASCII progress bar, as a string), and a loop of `open().read()` and `.write()` to do the actual copying. It displays the progress bar using `sys.stdout.write("\r%s\r" % (the_progress_bar))` which is a little hackish, but it works.

You can see the code (in context) [on github here](http://github.com/dbr/checktveps/tree/1be8f4445fbf766eba25f98f78ec52e955571608/autoPathTv.py#L64-153)

Is there any built-in module that will do this better? Is there any improvements that can be made to this code?

Comment: It copies TV episode files to a specific path ([fixed path]/$showname/$season_number]/), the files are generally 300-700MB in size

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two things:

- I would make the default block size a *lot* larger than 512. I would start with 16384 and perhaps more.
- For modularity, it might be better to have the `copy_with_prog` function not output the progress bar itself, but call a callback function so the caller can decide how to display the progress.

Perhaps something like this:

```
def copy_with_prog(src, dest, callback = None):
    while True:
        # copy loop stuff
        if callback:
            callback(pos, total)

prog = ProgressBar(...)
copy_with_prog(src, dest, lambda pos, total: prog.update(pos, total))
```

Answer (score 5):

Overkill?  Perhaps.  But on almost any system, Linux, Mac, and With a quick wxWidgets install on Windows, you can have the real deal, with pause and cancel buttons in a gui setup.  Macs ship with wxWidgets these days, and it's a common package on Linux.

A single file is very quick (it will immediately finish and look broken) so you might consider creating a fileSet job that ticks along once per file instead of once per block.  Enjoy!

-Jim Carroll

```
"""
Threaded Jobs.

Any class that does a long running process can inherit
from ThreadedJob.  This enables running as a background
thread, progress notification, pause and cancel.  The
time remaining is also calculated by the ThreadedJob class.
"""
import wx.lib.newevent
import thread
import exceptions
import time

(RunEvent, EVT_RUN) = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
(CancelEvent, EVT_CANCEL) = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
(DoneEvent, EVT_DONE) = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
(ProgressStartEvent, EVT_PROGRESS_START) = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
(ProgressEvent, EVT_PROGRESS) = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class InterruptedException(exceptions.Exception):
    def __init__(self, args = None):
        self.args = args
    #
#

class ThreadedJob:
    def __init__(self):
        # tell them ten seconds at first
        self.secondsRemaining = 10.0
        self.lastTick = 0

        # not running yet
        self.isPaused = False
        self.isRunning = False
        self.keepGoing = True

    def Start(self):
        self.keepGoing = self.isRunning = True
        thread.start_new_thread(self.Run, ())

        self.isPaused = False
    #

    def Stop(self):
        self.keepGoing = False
    #

    def WaitUntilStopped(self):
        while self.isRunning:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            wx.SafeYield()
        #
    #

    def IsRunning(self):
        return self.isRunning
    #

    def Run(self):
        # this is overridden by the
        # concrete ThreadedJob
        print "Run was not overloaded"
        self.JobFinished()

        pass
    #

    def Pause(self):
        self.isPaused = True
        pass
    #

    def Continue(self):
        self.isPaused = False
        pass
    #

    def PossibleStoppingPoint(self):
        if not self.keepGoing:
            raise InterruptedException("process interrupted.")
        wx.SafeYield()

        # allow cancel while paused
        while self.isPaused:
            if not self.keepGoing:
                raise InterruptedException("process interrupted.")

            # don't hog the CPU
            time.sleep(0.1)
        #
    #

    def SetProgressMessageWindow(self, win):
        self.win = win
    #

    def JobBeginning(self, totalTicks):

        self.lastIterationTime = time.time()
        self.totalTicks = totalTicks

        if hasattr(self, "win") and self.win:
            wx.PostEvent(self.win, ProgressStartEvent(total=totalTicks))
        #
    #

    def JobProgress(self, currentTick):
        dt = time.time() - self.lastIterationTime
        self.lastIterationTime = time.time()
        dtick = currentTick - self.lastTick
        self.lastTick = currentTick

        alpha = 0.92
        if currentTick > 1:
            self.secondsPerTick = dt * (1.0 - alpha) + (self.secondsPerTick * alpha)
        else:
            self.secondsPerTick = dt
        #

        if dtick > 0:
            self.secondsPerTick /= dtick

        self.secondsRemaining = self.secondsPerTick * (self.totalTicks - 1 - currentTick) + 1

        if hasattr(self, "win") and self.win:
            wx.PostEvent(self.win, ProgressEvent(count=currentTick))
        #
    #

    def SecondsRemaining(self):
        return self.secondsRemaining
    #

    def TimeRemaining(self):

        if 1: #self.secondsRemaining > 3:
            minutes = self.secondsRemaining // 60
            seconds = int(self.secondsRemaining % 60.0)
            return "%i:%02i" % (minutes, seconds)
        else:
            return "a few"
    #

    def JobFinished(self):
        if hasattr(self, "win") and self.win:
            wx.PostEvent(self.win, DoneEvent())
        #

        # flag we're done before we post the all done message
        self.isRunning = False
    #
#

class EggTimerJob(ThreadedJob):
    """ A sample Job that demonstrates the mechanisms and features of the Threaded Job"""
    def __init__(self, duration):
        self.duration = duration
        ThreadedJob.__init__(self)
    #

    def Run(self):
        """ This can either be run directly for synchronous use of the job,
        or started as a thread when ThreadedJob.Start() is called.

        It is responsible for calling JobBeginning, JobProgress, and JobFinished.
        And as often as possible, calling PossibleStoppingPoint() which will 
        sleep if the user pauses, and raise an exception if the user cancels.
        """
        self.time0 = time.clock()
        self.JobBeginning(self.duration)

        try:
            for count in range(0, self.duration):
                time.sleep(1.0)
                self.JobProgress(count)
                self.PossibleStoppingPoint()
            #
        except InterruptedException:
            # clean up if user stops the Job early
            print "canceled prematurely!"
        #

        # always signal the end of the job
        self.JobFinished()
        #
    #

    def __str__(self):
        """ The job progress dialog expects the job to describe its current state."""
        response = []
        if self.isPaused:
            response.append("Paused Counting")
        elif not self.isRunning:
            response.append("Will Count the seconds")
        else:
            response.append("Counting")
        #
        return " ".join(response)
    #
#

class FileCopyJob(ThreadedJob):
    """ A common file copy Job. """

    def __init__(self, orig_filename, copy_filename, block_size=32*1024):

        self.src = orig_filename
        self.dest = copy_filename
        self.block_size = block_size
        ThreadedJob.__init__(self)
    #

    def Run(self):
        """ This can either be run directly for synchronous use of the job,
        or started as a thread when ThreadedJob.Start() is called.

        It is responsible for calling JobBeginning, JobProgress, and JobFinished.
        And as often as possible, calling PossibleStoppingPoint() which will 
        sleep if the user pauses, and raise an exception if the user cancels.
        """
        self.time0 = time.clock()

        try:
            source = open(self.src, 'rb')

            # how many blocks?
            import os
            (st_mode, st_ino, st_dev, st_nlink, st_uid, st_gid, st_size, st_atime, st_mtime, st_ctime) = os.stat(self.src)
            num_blocks = st_size / self.block_size
            current_block = 0

            self.JobBeginning(num_blocks)

            dest = open(self.dest, 'wb')

            while 1:
                copy_buffer = source.read(self.block_size)
                if copy_buffer:
                    dest.write(copy_buffer)
                    current_block += 1
                    self.JobProgress(current_block)
                    self.PossibleStoppingPoint()
                else:
                    break

            source.close()
            dest.close()

        except InterruptedException:
            # clean up if user stops the Job early
            dest.close()
            # unlink / delete the file that is partially copied
            os.unlink(self.dest)
            print "canceled, dest deleted!"
        #

        # always signal the end of the job
        self.JobFinished()
        #
    #

    def __str__(self):
        """ The job progress dialog expects the job to describe its current state."""
        response = []
        if self.isPaused:
            response.append("Paused Copy")
        elif not self.isRunning:
            response.append("Will Copy a file")
        else:
            response.append("Copying")
        #
        return " ".join(response)
    #
#

class JobProgress(wx.Dialog):
    """ This dialog shows the progress of any ThreadedJob.

    It can be shown Modally if the main application needs to suspend
    operation, or it can be shown Modelessly for background progress
    reporting.

    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    job = EggTimerJob(duration = 10)
    dlg = JobProgress(None, job)
    job.SetProgressMessageWindow(dlg)
    job.Start()
    dlg.ShowModal()


    """
    def __init__(self, parent, job):
        self.job = job

        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Progress", size=(350,200))

        # vertical box sizer
        sizeAll = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Job status text
        self.JobStatusText = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Starting...")
        sizeAll.Add(self.JobStatusText, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 8)

        # wxGague
        self.ProgressBar = wx.Gauge(self, -1, 10, wx.DefaultPosition, (250, 15))
        sizeAll.Add(self.ProgressBar, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 8)

        # horiz box sizer, and spacer to right-justify
        sizeRemaining = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizeRemaining.Add((2,2), 1, wx.EXPAND)

        # time remaining read-only edit
        # putting wide default text gets a reasonable initial layout.
        self.remainingText = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "???:??")
        sizeRemaining.Add(self.remainingText, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 8)

        # static text: remaining
        self.remainingLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "remaining")
        sizeRemaining.Add(self.remainingLabel, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 8)

        # add that row to the mix
        sizeAll.Add(sizeRemaining, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        # horiz box sizer & spacer
        sizeButtons = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizeButtons.Add((2,2), 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ADJUST_MINSIZE)

        # Pause Button
        self.PauseButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Pause")
        sizeButtons.Add(self.PauseButton, 0, wx.ALL, 4)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPauseButton, self.PauseButton)

        # Cancel button
        self.CancelButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL, "Cancel")
        sizeButtons.Add(self.CancelButton, 0, wx.ALL, 4)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCancel, self.CancelButton)

        # Add all the buttons on the bottom row to the dialog
        sizeAll.Add(sizeButtons, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)

        self.SetSizer(sizeAll)
        #sizeAll.Fit(self)
        sizeAll.SetSizeHints(self)

        # jobs tell us how they are doing
        self.Bind(EVT_PROGRESS_START, self.OnProgressStart)
        self.Bind(EVT_PROGRESS, self.OnProgress)
        self.Bind(EVT_DONE, self.OnDone)

        self.Layout()
    #

    def OnPauseButton(self, event):
        if self.job.isPaused:
            self.job.Continue()
            self.PauseButton.SetLabel("Pause")
            self.Layout()
        else:
            self.job.Pause()
            self.PauseButton.SetLabel("Resume")
            self.Layout()
        #
    #

    def OnCancel(self, event):
        self.job.Stop()
    #

    def OnProgressStart(self, event):
        self.ProgressBar.SetRange(event.total)
        self.statusUpdateTime = time.clock()
    #

    def OnProgress(self, event):
        # update the progress bar
        self.ProgressBar.SetValue(event.count)

        self.remainingText.SetLabel(self.job.TimeRemaining())

        # update the text a max of 20 times a second
        if time.clock() - self.statusUpdateTime > 0.05:
            self.JobStatusText.SetLabel(str(self.job))
            self.statusUpdateTime = time.clock()
            self.Layout()
        #
    #

    # when a job is done
    def OnDone(self, event):
        self.ProgressBar.SetValue(0)
        self.JobStatusText.SetLabel("Finished")
        self.Destroy()
    #
#

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    #job = EggTimerJob(duration = 10)
    job = FileCopyJob("VeryBigFile.mp4", "/tmp/test_junk.mp4", 1024*1024*10)
    dlg = JobProgress(None, job)
    job.SetProgressMessageWindow(dlg)
    job.Start()
    dlg.ShowModal()
#
```

Comment: Hey... you forgot a # at the end of a while suite!

Ehm... what are they used for?

Comment: That's just because I really like to have my blocks closed... and it lets my text editor paste a line and automatically re-indent correctly.  Otherwise pasting might indent too far.

Answer (score 4):

I have this shutil.copy() with progress bar made in a simple way just with built in modules.
If you are using utf-8 encoding you can get a progress like the second example in the gif image:
[Progress bars examples for this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qocmx.gif)

Read the comments to change style and colors. The first and last examples don't need utf-8.
You can use the command CPprogress(SOURCE, DESTINATION) just where you had shutil.copy(src, dst):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
CPprogress(SOURCE, DESTINATION)

I made this to give shutil.copy() [or shutil.copy2() in this case] a progress bar.

You can use CPprogress(SOURCE, DESTINATION) just like shutil.copy(src, dst). SOURCE must be a file path and DESTINATION a file or folder path.

It will give you a progress bar for each file copied. Just copy this code above the place where you want to use CPprogress(SOURCE, DESTINATION) in your code.

You can easily change the look of the progress bar:
    - To keep the style and just change the colors, replace the colors values of progressCOLOR and finalCOLOR (orange code at the end of the lines).
    - The use a solid block progress bar, # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- is required. Otherwise, you will get an encoding error. Some basic terminals, like xterm, may not show the progress bar because of the utf-8 characters.
      To use this style, remove the comments #STYLE# in lines ###COLORS### - BlueCOLOR and endBLOCK.
      In def getPERCECENTprogress() remove the comments  #STYLE# AND COMMENT THE PREVIOUS line. Do the same in def CPprogress()
      If you don't want the utf-8 encoding, delete the four lines beginning with #STYLE#.

NOTE: If you want to copy lots of small files, the copy process for file is so fast 
      that all you will see is a lot of lines scrolling in you terminal window - not enough time for a 'progress'.
      In that case, I use an overall progress that shows only one progress bar to the complete job.   nzX
'''
import os
import shutil
import sys
import threading
import time

######## COLORS ######
progressCOLOR = '\033[38;5;33;48;5;236m' #\033[38;5;33;48;5;236m# copy inside '' for colored progressbar| orange:#\033[38;5;208;48;5;235m
finalCOLOR =  '\033[38;5;33;48;5;33m' #\033[38;5;33;48;5;33m# copy inside '' for colored progressbar| orange:#\033[38;5;208;48;5;208m
#STYLE#BlueCOLOR = '\033[38;5;33m'#\033[38;5;33m# copy inside '' for colored progressbar Orange#'\033[38;5;208m'# # BG progress# #STYLE# 
#STYLE#endBLOCK = '' # ▌ copy OR '' for none # BG progress# #STYLE# requires utf8 coding header
########

BOLD    = '\033[1m'
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
CEND    = '\033[0m'

def getPERCECENTprogress(source_path, destination_path):
    time.sleep(.24)
    if os.path.exists(destination_path):
        while os.path.getsize(source_path) != os.path.getsize(destination_path):
            sys.stdout.write('\r')
            percentagem = int((float(os.path.getsize(destination_path))/float(os.path.getsize(source_path))) * 100)
            steps = int(percentagem/5)
            copiado = int(os.path.getsize(destination_path)/1000000)# Should be 1024000 but this get's equal to Thunar file manager report (Linux - Xfce)
            sizzz = int(os.path.getsize(source_path)/1000000)
            sys.stdout.write(("         {:d} / {:d} Mb   ".format(copiado, sizzz)) +  (BOLD + progressCOLOR + "{:20s}".format('|'*steps) + CEND) + ("   {:d}% ".format(percentagem))) # BG progress
            #STYLE#sys.stdout.write(("         {:d} / {:d} Mb   ".format(copiado, sizzz)) +  (BOLD + BlueCOLOR + "▐" + "{:s}".format('█'*steps) + CEND) + ("{:s}".format(' '*(20-steps))+ BOLD + BlueCOLOR + endBLOCK+ CEND) +("   {:d}% ".format(percentagem))) #STYLE# # BG progress# closer to GUI but less compatible (no block bar with xterm) # requires utf8 coding header
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(.01)

def CPprogress(SOURCE, DESTINATION):
    if os.path.isdir(DESTINATION):
        dst_file = os.path.join(DESTINATION, os.path.basename(SOURCE))
    else: dst_file = DESTINATION
    print " "
    print (BOLD + UNDERLINE + "FROM:" + CEND + "   "), SOURCE
    print (BOLD + UNDERLINE + "TO:" + CEND + "     "), dst_file
    print " "
    threading.Thread(name='progresso', target=getPERCECENTprogress, args=(SOURCE, dst_file)).start()
    shutil.copy2(SOURCE, DESTINATION)
    time.sleep(.02)
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.write(("         {:d} / {:d} Mb   ".format((int(os.path.getsize(dst_file)/1000000)), (int(os.path.getsize(SOURCE)/1000000)))) +  (BOLD + finalCOLOR + "{:20s}".format('|'*20) + CEND) + ("   {:d}% ".format(100))) # BG progress 100%
    #STYLE#sys.stdout.write(("         {:d} / {:d} Mb   ".format((int(os.path.getsize(dst_file)/1000000)), (int(os.path.getsize(SOURCE)/1000000)))) +  (BOLD + BlueCOLOR + "▐" + "{:s}{:s}".format(('█'*20), endBLOCK) + CEND) + ("   {:d}% ".format(100))) #STYLE# # BG progress 100%# closer to GUI but less compatible (no block bar with xterm) # requires utf8 coding header
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print " "
    print " "

'''
#Ex. Copy all files from root of the source dir to destination dir

folderA = '/path/to/SOURCE' # SOURCE
folderB = '/path/to/DESTINATION' # DESTINATION
for FILE in os.listdir(folderA):
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folderA, FILE)):
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(folderB, FILE)): continue # as we are using shutil.copy2() that overwrites destination, this skips existing files
        CPprogress(os.path.join(folderA, FILE), folderB) # use the command as if it was shutil.copy2() but with progress


         75 / 150 Mb  ||||||||||         |  50%
'''
```

Answer (score 3):

The following uses `tqdm` to generate a progress bar while copying a single file.

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

def copy_with_progress(src, dst):
    size = os.path.getsize(src)
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
        with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
            with tqdm(total=size, unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc=f'Copying {src} to {dst}') as pbar:
                while True:
                    chunk = fsrc.read(4096)
                    if not chunk:
                        break
                    fdst.write(chunk)
                    pbar.update(len(chunk))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Windows copy dialog with progress you can use these:

- https://github.com/tjguk/winshell/
- https://github.com/frmdstryr/pywinutils

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `ROBOCOPY` with the `os` module. It won't give you a progress bar, but it'll give you a percentage indicator as well as a robust summary at the end.

```py
import os

def robocopy(source, destination, extension=''):
    os.system("robocopy {} {} {} /xx /njh".format(source, destination, extension))

# Usage example
robocopy(r'C:\Users\Example\Downloads', r'C:\Users\Example\Desktop', '*.mov')
```

The example above will copy all .mov files to the desktop

Leaving `extension` blank will copy all files in the source folder to the destination folder.

`/xx` removes extra files/directories from being listed

`/njh` removes job header

See documentation for more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Answer (score 0):

If you want an overall progress, you can use something like this (made for another script). Note that in this case, the 'threading.Thread' that calls the progress bar was placed outside the 'for' loop. Also, the measures need be taken in a different way. This is the third example (non utf-8) from the gif image in the previous answer. It adds a files 'ToGo’ counting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
Ex.
CopyProgress('/path/to/SOURCE', '/path/to/DESTINATION')


I think this 'copy with overall progress' is very 'plastic' and can be easily adapted.
By default, it will RECURSIVELY copy the CONTENT of  'path/to/SOURCE' to 'path/to/DESTINATION/' keeping the directory tree.

Paying attention to comments, there are 4 main options that can be immediately change:

1 - The LOOK of the progress bar: see COLORS and the PAIR of STYLE lines in 'def getPERCECENTprogress'(inside and after the 'while' loop);

2 - The DESTINATION path: to get 'path/to/DESTINATION/SOURCE_NAME' as target, comment the 2nd 'DST =' definition on the top of the 'def CopyProgress(SOURCE, DESTINATION)' function;

3 - If you don't want to RECURSIVELY copy from sub-directories but just the files in the root source directory to the root of destination, you can use os.listdir() instead of os.walk(). Read the comments inside 'def CopyProgress(SOURCE, DESTINATION)' function to disable RECURSION. Be aware that the RECURSION changes(4x2) must be made in both os.walk() loops;

4 - Handling destination files: if you use this in a situation where the destination filename may already exist, by default, the file is skipped and the loop will jump to the next and so on. On the other way shutil.copy2(), by default, overwrites destination file if exists. Alternatively, you can handle files that exist by overwriting or renaming (according to current date and time). To do that read the comments after 'if os.path.exists(dstFILE): continue' both in the count bytes loop and the main loop. Be aware that the changes must match in both loops (as described in comments) or the progress function will not work properly.

'''

import os
import shutil
import sys
import threading
import time

progressCOLOR = '\033[38;5;33;48;5;236m' #BLUEgreyBG
finalCOLOR =  '\033[48;5;33m' #BLUEBG
# check the color codes below and paste above

###### COLORS #######
# WHITEblueBG = '\033[38;5;15;48;5;33m'
# BLUE = '\033[38;5;33m'
# BLUEBG  = '\033[48;5;33m'
# ORANGEBG = '\033[48;5;208m'
# BLUEgreyBG = '\033[38;5;33;48;5;236m'
# ORANGEgreyBG = '\033[38;5;208;48;5;236m' # = '\033[38;5;FOREGROUND;48;5;BACKGROUNDm' # ver 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTSQa.png' para 256 color codes
# INVERT = '\033[7m'
###### COLORS #######

BOLD    = '\033[1m'
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
CEND    = '\033[0m'

FilesLeft = 0

def FullFolderSize(path):
    TotalSize = 0
    if os.path.exists(path):# to be safely used # if FALSE returns 0
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                TotalSize += os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, file))
    return TotalSize

def getPERCECENTprogress(source_path, destination_path, bytes_to_copy):
    dstINIsize = FullFolderSize(destination_path)
    time.sleep(.25)
    print " "
    print (BOLD + UNDERLINE + "FROM:" + CEND + "   "), source_path
    print (BOLD + UNDERLINE + "TO:" + CEND + "     "), destination_path
    print " "
    if os.path.exists(destination_path):
        while bytes_to_copy != (FullFolderSize(destination_path)-dstINIsize):
            sys.stdout.write('\r')
            percentagem = int((float((FullFolderSize(destination_path)-dstINIsize))/float(bytes_to_copy)) * 100)
            steps = int(percentagem/5)
            copiado = '{:,}'.format(int((FullFolderSize(destination_path)-dstINIsize)/1000000))# Should be 1024000 but this get's closer to the file manager report
            sizzz = '{:,}'.format(int(bytes_to_copy/1000000))
            sys.stdout.write(("         {:s} / {:s} Mb  ".format(copiado, sizzz)) +  (BOLD + progressCOLOR + "{:20s}".format('|'*steps) + CEND) + ("  {:d}% ".format(percentagem)) + ("  {:d} ToGo ".format(FilesLeft))) #  STYLE 1 progress default # 
            #BOLD# sys.stdout.write(BOLD + ("        {:s} / {:s} Mb  ".format(copiado, sizzz)) +  (progressCOLOR + "{:20s}".format('|'*steps) + CEND) + BOLD + ("  {:d}% ".format(percentagem)) + ("  {:d} ToGo ".format(FilesLeft))+ CEND) # STYLE 2 progress BOLD # 
            #classic B/W# sys.stdout.write(BOLD + ("        {:s} / {:s} Mb  ".format(copiado, sizzz)) +  ("|{:20s}|".format('|'*steps)) + ("  {:d}% ".format(percentagem)) + ("  {:d} ToGo ".format(FilesLeft))+ CEND) # STYLE 3 progress classic B/W #
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(.01)
        sys.stdout.write('\r')
        time.sleep(.05)
        sys.stdout.write(("         {:s} / {:s} Mb  ".format('{:,}'.format(int((FullFolderSize(destination_path)-dstINIsize)/1000000)), '{:,}'.format(int(bytes_to_copy/1000000)))) +  (BOLD + finalCOLOR + "{:20s}".format(' '*20) + CEND) + ("  {:d}% ".format( 100)) + ("  {:s}      ".format('    ')) + "\n") #  STYLE 1 progress default # 
        #BOLD# sys.stdout.write(BOLD + ("        {:s} / {:s} Mb  ".format('{:,}'.format(int((FullFolderSize(destination_path)-dstINIsize)/1000000)), '{:,}'.format(int(bytes_to_copy/1000000)))) +  (finalCOLOR + "{:20s}".format(' '*20) + CEND) + BOLD + ("  {:d}% ".format( 100)) + ("  {:s}      ".format('    ')) + "\n" + CEND ) # STYLE 2 progress BOLD # 
        #classic B/W# sys.stdout.write(BOLD + ("        {:s} / {:s} Mb  ".format('{:,}'.format(int((FullFolderSize(destination_path)-dstINIsize)/1000000)), '{:,}'.format(int(bytes_to_copy/1000000)))) +  ("|{:20s}|".format('|'*20)) + ("  {:d}% ".format( 100)) + ("  {:s}      ".format('    ')) + "\n" + CEND ) # STYLE 3 progress classic B/W # 
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print " "
        print " "

def CopyProgress(SOURCE, DESTINATION):
    global FilesLeft
    DST = os.path.join(DESTINATION, os.path.basename(SOURCE))
    # <- the previous will copy the Source folder inside of the Destination folder. Result Target: path/to/Destination/SOURCE_NAME
    # -> UNCOMMENT the next (# DST = DESTINATION) to copy the CONTENT of Source to the Destination. Result Target: path/to/Destination
    DST = DESTINATION # UNCOMMENT this to specify the Destination as the target itself and not the root folder of the target 
    #
    if DST.startswith(SOURCE):
        print " "
        print BOLD + UNDERLINE + 'Source folder can\'t be changed.' + CEND
        print 'Please check your target path...'
        print " "
        print BOLD + '        CANCELED' + CEND
        print " "
        exit()
    #count bytes to copy
    Bytes2copy = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SOURCE): # USE for filename in os.listdir(SOURCE): # if you don't want RECURSION #
        dstDIR = root.replace(SOURCE, DST, 1) # USE dstDIR = DST # if you don't want RECURSION #
        for filename in files:                # USE if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(SOURCE, filename)): # if you don't want RECURSION #
            dstFILE = os.path.join(dstDIR, filename)
            if os.path.exists(dstFILE): continue # must match the main loop (after "threading.Thread")
            #                                      To overwrite delete dstFILE first here so the progress works properly: ex. change continue to os.unlink(dstFILE)
            #                                      To rename new files adding date and time, instead of deleating and overwriting, 
            #                                      comment 'if os.path.exists(dstFILE): continue'
            Bytes2copy += os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, filename)) # USE os.path.getsize(os.path.join(SOURCE, filename)) # if you don't want RECURSION #
            FilesLeft += 1
    # <- count bytes to copy
    #
    # Treading to call the preogress
    threading.Thread(name='progresso', target=getPERCECENTprogress, args=(SOURCE, DST, Bytes2copy)).start()
    # main loop
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SOURCE): # USE for filename in os.listdir(SOURCE): # if you don't want RECURSION #
        dstDIR = root.replace(SOURCE, DST, 1) # USE dstDIR = DST # if you don't want RECURSION #
        if not os.path.exists(dstDIR):
            os.makedirs(dstDIR)
        for filename in files:                # USE if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(SOURCE, filename)): # if you don't want RECURSION #
            srcFILE = os.path.join(root, filename) # USE os.path.join(SOURCE, filename) # if you don't want RECURSION #
            dstFILE = os.path.join(dstDIR, filename)
            if os.path.exists(dstFILE): continue # MUST MATCH THE PREVIOUS count bytes loop 
            #   <- <-                              this jumps to the next file without copying this file, if destination file exists. 
            #                                      Comment to copy with rename or overwrite dstFILE
            #
            # RENAME part below
            head, tail = os.path.splitext(filename)
            count = -1
            year = int(time.strftime("%Y"))
            month = int(time.strftime("%m"))
            day = int(time.strftime("%d"))
            hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))
            minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))
            while os.path.exists(dstFILE):
                count += 1
                if count == 0:
                    dstFILE = os.path.join(dstDIR, '{:s}[{:d}.{:d}.{:d}]{:d}-{:d}{:s}'.format(head, year, month, day, hour, minute, tail))
                else:
                    dstFILE = os.path.join(dstDIR, '{:s}[{:d}.{:d}.{:d}]{:d}-{:d}[{:d}]{:s}'.format(head, year, month, day, hour, minute, count, tail))
            # END of RENAME part
            shutil.copy2(srcFILE, dstFILE)
            FilesLeft -= 1
            #

'''
Ex.
CopyProgress('/path/to/SOURCE', '/path/to/DESTINATION')
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

That is simple PySide app can copy any file from source to destination

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QProgressBar, QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, Signal, Slot


class ProgressDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, source, destination):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.resize(400, 50)
        
        self.parent = parent
        self.source = source
        self.destination = destination
        
        self.prog = QProgressBar(self)
        self.prog.setMaximum(100)
        self.prog.setMinimum(0)
        self.prog.setFormat("%p%")

    def start(self):
        self.show()
        self.copy()

    def copy(self):
        copy_thread = CopyThread(self, self.source, self.destination)
        copy_thread.procPartDone.connect(self.update_progress)
        copy_thread.procDone.connect(self.finished_copy)
        copy_thread.start()

    def update_progress(self, progress):
        self.prog.setValue(progress)

    def finished_copy(self, state):
        self.close()

class CopyThread(QThread):

    procDone = Signal(bool)
    procPartDone = Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent, source: str, destination: str):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.source = source
        self.destination = destination

    def run(self):
        self.copy()
        self.procDone.emit(True)

    def copy(self):
        source_size = os.stat(self.source).st_size
        copied = 0

        with open(self.source, "rb") as source, open(self.destination, "wb") as target:
            while True:
                chunk = source.read(1024)
                if not chunk:
                    break

                target.write(chunk)
                copied += len(chunk)

                self.procPartDone.emit(copied * 100 / source_size)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent: object = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.src = "/path/to/file.ext"
        self.dest = "/path/to/file.ext"

        self.btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.setText("Start copy")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.run)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.btn)
        
    def run(self):
        self.prog = ProgressDialog(self, self.src, self.dest)
        self.prog.start()


def main():   
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

##### Save this script in the 'main.py' file and execute the command

```sh
python3 main.py
```